# Showing that an increasing sequence is not bounded above.

Tags: real-analysis

Can anyone give me any tips as to how you would do this for a sequence that you know is monotonously increasing but is divergent to infinity?

For example, let $a(1) = 1, a(n+1) = a(n)^2 + a(n)/2 + 1/16$

I can show that it is an increasing sequence, but I am not sure how to go about showing it is not bounded above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Rewrite
$$a(n+1) = a(n)^2 + a(n)/2 + 1/16=[a(n)+1/4]^2$$ and look for the first number using $a(1)=1$. The terms increase very fast as a function of $n$.

Comment: Working with [a(n) + 1/4]^2 helps, but im still unsure as to how you show that it is unbounded. I can see intuitively that the terms increase faster and faster, I just don't know how to write it out.

Comment: You square a positive number greater than $1$ each time.

Comment: I can see that would make it diverge, but how do I go about showing that that doesn't make a(n)<M? I have absolutely no idea how you are supposed to do this even though it seems blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Can you write $a(n+1)=$[something greater than $a(n)$]$+c$, where $c$ is a fixed positive number]? What does this imply about the value of $a(n+1)$ in terms of $a(1)$ and $c$?

Comment: I think I get what you are saying, do you mean a(n+1) = a(n)^2 + a(n)/2 + 16. But a(n)^2 + a(n)2 > a(n), since a(n)^2>1 so a(n+1) > a(n) + 1/16. Am I on the right track from here?

Comment: That's perfect. You seem confused you how to prove boundedness at all, so I'll give you the rest.

Comment: Let M be arbitrary. By your equation, $a(n+1)>\frac{n}{16}$. Thus $a(16M+17)>M+1$

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me but I managed to finish it off (I think). The way I did it was choose K/16>M. Then a(K+1)> a(K) + K/16>M. Is this allowed?

Comment: It depends on the inequality you used, but that looks very natural.